# Inconsistent view radius in iOS (9+) using nibs ( .xib) and Swift 5 / Xcode 11.3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a chat app built with Xcode 11.3 compiled for iOS 9.0+,  and want to display chat bubbles with 3 "radius 12" corners and one "radius 3" corner. The "Corner Radius" setting on the view is set to 3, so if nothing is changed the view has all four corners set with a radius of 3. These views are in cells in a tableView. With the three larger radiuses properly set, the chat bubbles should look like this:

[image]

Here's the Nib:

[image]

And the code that uses a view extension to add the radii when a new chat bubble is created and populated with text:

```
@IBDesignable
class ChatSent: NibDesignable {
    @IBOutlet weak var itemText: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var itemBubbleSent: UIView!

    @IBInspectable
    public var Text: String = "" {
        didSet {
            self.itemText.text = Text
            itemBubbleSent.roundSentCorners([.topLeft, .topRight, .bottomLeft], radius: 12)
        }
    }
}

extension UIView {
    func roundSentCorners(_ corners:UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.path = path.cgPath
    self.layer.mask = mask
  }
}
```

and in the main view controller, text in the chat bubble is set like this:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Chat Sent", for: indexPath) as! ChatViewSentCellView
cell.myChatViewSent.Text = self.messageData[self.messageIndex!].messages[indexPath.item - 10]
```

So, the problem is the radius corners aren't properly created. They are consistently inconsistent, meaning the same errors are occurring on each bubble when the view is loaded. Further, by scrolling up and down the bubbles can be made to draw properly, only to return to the improper display when scrolling  up to the next group of bubbles. Notice that some corners have wrong or no radius, and some bubbles are offset:

[image: chat bubbles not drawn properly]

What is happening here?

Comment: I'll have to analyze it a little more, but in my experience when doing something similar, I found it much more reliable to use some good old-fashioned geometry and make a function that draws out a custom `UIBezierPath` for my needs. Basically like starting the path at (0, height/2), then drawing up to the point where the rounding would start (which you could determine based on passing in the radius of the corner), drawing an arc, and then repeating for every corner you want clipped. Might seem more complicated, but I've found it very reliable.

Comment: @Pierce So the view extension is using UIBezierPath so how would your method differ?

Comment: http://www.programmingios.net/premature-layout/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem lays within the `frame` you are passing to your function, since the cell haven't calculated it's layout yet, you should be doing something like this:

first:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Chat Sent", for: indexPath) as! ChatViewSentCellView
cell.myChatViewSent.text = self.messageData[self.messageIndex!].messages[indexPath.item - 10]
```

then in your custom table cell class:

```swift
class CellWithCustomLayout: UITableViewCell {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        itemBubbleSent.layoutIfNeeded()
        //Mask your view with the path here, the view has the proper frame now, i.e:
        itemBubbleSent.roundSentCorners([.topLeft, .topRight, .bottomLeft], radius: 12)
    }
}
```

You can change the code to suit your needs, but generally after `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and `layoutSubviews` the frame is calculated and ready to be used.

Comment: This answer works perfectly. +1 to @matt for the premature-layout link in the OP comment.

Answer (score 2):

This example I'm giving is by no means the most efficient way to accomplish this, as other people have mentioned, your problem seems to be related to the views being drawn before everything has been laid out - so the frames aren't consistent. This example I'm giving you could help if you know the size of your view before you display it, and it also could be really helpful if you want to make a custom looking speech bubble like you see in iMessage with the little curved tail (obviously that would take a little more path calculation, but if you know some basic trig/geometry it should be very easy). Here is an example that's hard-coded to not round off the bottom right edge:

```
func makePath(for bubbleView: UIView, with cornerRadius: CGFloat) -> UIBezierPath {
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    let height = bubbleView.frame.height
    let width = bubbleView.frame.width
    let π = CGFloat.pi
    // The (0,0) coordinate for a UIBezierPath starts off at the top left corner, not the bottom left like you'd think back in math class.
    let startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: height/2)
    path.move(to: startPoint)
    // Draw the line up to where the corner would start
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: cornerRadius))
    // Add the top left corner
    path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: cornerRadius, y: cornerRadius), radius: cornerRadius, startAngle: π, endAngle: 3*π/2, clockwise: true)
    // Draw to the top right corner
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width-cornerRadius, y: 0))
    // Draw the top right corner
    path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: width-cornerRadius, y: cornerRadius), radius: cornerRadius, startAngle: 3*π/2, endAngle: 0, clockwise: true)
    // Draw line to the bottom right (no rounded corner)
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: height))
    // If you wanted to round this corner you would add the commented out arc below
    //path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: width-cornerRadius, y: height-cornerRadius), radius: cornerRadius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: π/2, clockwise: true)

    // Draw line to the bottom left corner
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: cornerRadius, y: height))
    // Draw the bottom left corner
    path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: cornerRadius, y: height-cornerRadius), radius: cornerRadius, startAngle: π/2, endAngle: π, clockwise: true)
    // End the line drawing back to the starting point
    path.addLine(to: startPoint)
    return path
}
```

For me that produced something like this:
[image]

You should also be able to see how you could easily add some parameters and a switch statement to customize this method to clip off multiple corners, or vary which corner gets the clipped tail